# Implications on AVCapturePhotoOutput preparedPhotoSettingsArray

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, photo

In AVFoundation, the `AVCapturePhotoSettings` class enables the developer to configure a photo capture to their needs.

Inside `AVCapturePhotoOutput`, the developer has an option to call the `setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray(_:completionHandler:)` method, which will set the capture settings for the photo output beforehand. This is done in order to (from the documentation): "Prevent photo capture requests from executing slowly due to lazy resource allocation."

The other method of setting the capture settings is setting the `AVCapturePhotoSettings` at capture time via the `capturePhoto(with:delegate:)` method in `AVCapturePhotoOutput`.

I want to set certain capture settings beforehand using `setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray(_:completionHandler:)`. These settings are the configurations that I know I will definitely be using.

I also have certain capture settings that can be toggled, and therefore, I cannot guarantee that I will use certain configurations. I would like to instead set these settings with `capturePhoto(with:delegate:)` at capture time. I want to know how I can do this.

Reading through Apple documentation, my interpretation is that calling `capturePhoto(with:delegate:)` will override the previous `preparedPhotoSettingsArray` that I had set with `setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray(_:completionHandler:)`. I would like to append additional specifications/settings onto the existing `preparedPhotoSettingsArray` ad hoc, not override them.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood it, `setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray` is not actually *setting* the settings to use during the next capture, but rather *hinting* the system what settings you are (likely) going to use, so that it can prepare resources beforehand and speed up the actual capture.

That means you always configure the `AVCapturePhotoSettings` for the current capture, regardless of what you told the system before with `setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray`. If the current settings differ from those that you prepared, the system may take a bit longer for this capture since it needs to allocate resources first.

I guess best practice would be to call `setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray` as soon as the user changes capture settings in the interface, assuming that he/she takes a bit of time between changing settings and the actual capture, so that the system can prepare during that time.